# Undefined variable when trying to Mail::send

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to insert results into my e-mail view and then use foreach to display data however I keep **getting**

> "Undefined variable: results"

. How could I fix that?

Here is my **controller code:**

```
$results = $sales->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

Mail::send('mailings.emails.' . $view, $data, function($message) use ($person, $results, $title )
            {
                $message->to($person->peopleEmail, $person->peopleFirstName . ' ' . $person->peopleLastName)->subject($title);
            });
```

Here is my **blade:**

```
@foreach($results as $result)
<table class="row">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper last">

            <table class="twelve columns">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h5 style="text-align:center;">{{$result->SaleID}}</h5>
                    </td>
                    <td class="expander"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail

$results is not being passed:

```
 Mail::send('mailings.emails.' . $view, $data, function($message) use ($person, $results, $title )
        {
            $message->to($person->peopleEmail, $person->peopleFirstName . ' ' . $person->peopleLastName)->subject($title);
        });
```

You need to pass it as :

```
$data = ['results' => $results];//ADD this line

 Mail::send('mailings.emails.' . $view, $data, function($message) use ($person, $results, $title )
        {
            $message->to($person->peopleEmail, $person->peopleFirstName . ' ' . $person->peopleLastName)->subject($title);
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I just discovered it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = array('mailTo' => $serviceProviderEmail, 'subject' => $subject ,'mailBody' => $message);
Mail::send('template_name', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from('no-reply@xyz.com', 'xyz');
    $message->to($data['mailTo'])->subject($data['subject']);
});
```

I am using this syntax and it is working fine.